# Is $\{a^n b^m : 1 \le m \le 2^{2^n}\}$ a permitting-context language?

Tags: fl.formal-languages

A random permitting-context grammar is a context-free grammar $(N, \Sigma, P, S)$ equipped with a function $p : P \rightarrow 2^N$. The rule $A \rightarrow x$ can be applied to $uAw \Rightarrow uxw$ if every symbol in $p(A\rightarrow x)$ appears in $uw$. A forbidding-context grammar is similar, except  equipped with a function $f : P \rightarrow 2^N$, and a rule application is allowed if *no* symbol from $f(A\rightarrow x)$ appears in $uw$.

$\{a^n b^m : 1 \le m \le 2^n\}$ is a random permitting-context language (RPCL), though $\{a^n b^m : m = 2^n\}$ is not (as can be proved by Ewert and Van der Walt's pumping lemma for RPCLs). In a permitting grammar we can *allow* the  nonterminals of some type to double, but we can't *force* it.

> It seems obvious to me that one can't get *more* than exponential
>   growth, but I can't see how to prove it (the pumping lemma certainly
>   doesn't help, since it will just increase the number of $a$'s). Is
>   there a known result that helps here?
>
> I'm also interested in superexponential growth in forbidding languages
>   (e.g. is $\{a^{2^{2^n}} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ an RFCL).

Comment: It might be helpful to link to, or provide inline, a definition of "permitting context"

Comment: @SureshVenkat: good idea, done.

Comment: What does "random" mean in this context ?

Comment: The idea is that the context could appear at "any random position", rather than adjacent as in a CSG. However, it seems to me that "global" would have been a better choice.

Comment: A (not too) recent overview on regulated rewriting is here: Dassow, Jürgen, [http://theo.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/dassow/tarraphd.pdf ''Grammars with Regulated Rewriting'']. Lecture in the 5th PhD Program "Formal Languages and Applications", Tarragona, Spain, 2006.